# How can Salesforce Platform users edit Managed Package Email Templates?

Tags: salesforce, email-templates

Profile with "Salesforce Platform user" are unable to edit Managed Package "Email Template" Only System Administration are able to edit Managed Package Email temaplte.

Initially "Classic email template" option is not visible in setup.

Then, Creating new permission set for that user

1. Edit HTML Templates
2. Manage Public Classic Email Templates
3. Manage Public Lightning Email Templates

But after givining these permission , I am able to dispaly "Classic Email Tempalte" in Setup and with the help of it now i can preview the email template .

But still i can't edit email template.

[Note:- I also change test by giving other license and profile but they also can not edit Email Template only "System Admin" can access that email tempalte .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.